# Dynamically Calculate difference columns based off slicer- POWERBI

Tags: dynamic, powerbi

I have a table with quarterly volume data, and a slicer that allows you to choose what quarter/year you want to see volume per code for. The slicer has 2019Q1 through 2021Q4 selections.  I need to create dynamic difference column that will adjust depending on what quarter/year is selected in the slicer. I know I need to create a new measure using Calculate/filter but am a beginner in PowerBI and am unsure how to write that formula.

Example of raw table data:

| Code | 2019Q1 | 2019Q2 | 2019Q3 | 2019Q | 2020Q1 | 2020Q2 | 2020Q3 | 2020Q4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 232 | 283 | 289 | 19 | 222 | 283 | 289 | 19 |
| 22222 | 117 | 481 | 231 | 31 | 232 | 286 | 2 | 19 |
| 11111 | 232 | 397 | 94 | 444 | 232 | 553 | 0 | 188 |
| 22222 | 117 | 411 | 15 | 14 | 232 | 283 | 25 | 189 |

Example if 2019Q1 and 2020Q1 are selected:

| Code | 2019Q1 | 2020Q1 | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 232 | 222 | 10 |
| 22222 | 117 | 481 | -364 |
| 11111 | 232 | 397 | -165 |
| 22222 | 117 | 411 | -294 |

Answer (score 0):

Power BI doesn't work that way. This is an Excel pivot table setup. You don't have any parameter to distinguish first and third or second and fourth row. They have the same code, so Power BI will aggregate their volumes. You could introduce a hidden index column but then why don't you simply stick to Excel? The Power BI approch to the problem would be to unpivot (stack) your table to a Code, Quarter and a Volume column, create 2 independent slicer tables for Minuend and Subtrahend and then CALCULATE your aggregated differences based on the SELECTEDVALUE of the 2 slicers.